# How to add multidimensional array elements using a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm having trouble with the looping of what I want to do.

I have an array called `$data` which at present holds only two elements:

```
array(2) {
  ["pagination"]=>
  string(166) "https://someURL.com"
  ["images"]=>
  string(3) "foo"
}
```

I now wish to add another dimension, within the `[images]` element. And again within that element, another two pieces of data. The result would look like this:

```
array(2) {
  ["pagination"]=>
  string(166) "https://someURL.com"
  ["images"]=> array(5) {
      [0]=> array(2){
        ["image_url"]=> string(1234) "http://www.blah.com"
        ["caption"]=> string(1234) "Here is my caption strng"
      }
      [1]=> array(2){
        ["image_url"]=> string(1234) "http://www.blah.com"
        ["caption"]=> string(1234) "Here is my caption strng"
      } 
      [2]=> array(2){
        ["image_url"]=> string(1234) "http://www.blah.com"
        ["caption"]=> string(1234) "Here is my caption strng"
      } 
      [3]=> array(2){
        ["image_url"]=> string(1234) "http://www.blah.com"
        ["caption"]=> string(1234) "Here is my caption strng"
      } 
      [4]=> array(2){
        ["image_url"]=> string(1234) "http://www.blah.com"
        ["caption"]=> string(1234) "Here is my caption strng"
      }  
}
```

My question is, how I can extract data from it's original source (an array called `$pics`) and input it into my new `[images]` element in the manner above?

At present I am able to output the `image_url` and `caption` data using the following loop, I just can't figure out how to push that data into the array above.

```
foreach($pics['data'] as $pic){
    $caption = $pic['caption']['text'];
    $image = $pic['images']['standard_resolution']['url'];
}
```

Comment: Can anybody explain why this question is "too broad" when it provides actual code and a specific example of what is trying to be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
foreach($pics['data'] as $pics)
{
     $caption = $pic['caption']['text'];
     $image = $pic['images']['standard_resolution']['url'];
     $data['images'][] = array($image, $caption);
}
```

EDIT: $data['images'] must be set as an array *before* the foreach statement: `$data['images'] = array();`

Comment: Hi there, I got the following error `Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings`

Comment: No, that's due to the fact that the 'image' index must not be a string. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thank you, I added the array initialisation to the original array. Could you also let me know how it would be possible to properly name the key for the image and the caption? At present it is all nearly there except they are [0] and [1] instead. Is this something that can be done at the same time as inputting the data or would it need to be renamed after? Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can do that this way: `array( "image" => $image, "caption" => $caption);`